# Как занести аватарку в базу данных?

Tags: php, html

В регистрации есть несколько картинок (аватарок). Как сделать так, чтобы выбранная картинка занеслась в таблицу `avatarka`?

Comment: Брать имя (адрес) картинки и заносить это как обычные данные в таблицу?

Comment: Ну блин их несколько есть

Comment: Ну они же отличаются именами? Бери имя выбранной картинки и заноси в БД.

Comment: Форимруешь навзвание аватарки по `id` пользователя, в БД делаешь таблицу вида `user_id, format`, делаешь FOREIGN KEY с таблицей пользователей, все аватары хранишь в одной папке, соответственно отрисовываешь аватра как `$user['id'] . $avatar['format']`, примерно так самое "легкое" решение...<br>
так-же можно хранить инфу не только о формате, но и. например о размерах картинки, естественно если в этом есть необходимость...<br>
Вообще странный вопрос честно говоря -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В любой СУБД есть поле `blob`. Данные хранятся и обрабатываются как массив байт. Например, в SQLite: [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: Если именно изображение необходимо заносить, то да..<br>
Правда тогда, так-же, необходимо будет поле с инфой о формате аватарки....

Comment: В вопросе стояло, что нужно хранить картинку, а не ссылку на неё.

Comment: тогда, совет - это "крайности" хранить картинки в бд =)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, например аватарки выбираются с помощью select`а с name=avatarka. В обработчике пишем:

```
$href = mysql_escape_string($_POST['avatarka']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO avatarka(iduser,href) VALUES('$iduser','$href')") or die(mysql_error()); //Где iduser - это id пользователя.
```